# Unexpected result from parallel processing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have this code on a click event handler of a button:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<MyMatrix> myMatrices = new List<MyMatrix> {
                       new MyMatrix { LineNumber = 200, ColumnNumber = 30 }.GenerateRandomMatrix(),
                       new MyMatrix { LineNumber = 1, ColumnNumber = 1 }.GenerateRandomMatrix(),
                       new MyMatrix { LineNumber = 200, ColumnNumber = 40 }.GenerateRandomMatrix(),
                       new MyMatrix { LineNumber = 100, ColumnNumber = 50 }.GenerateRandomMatrix(),
                       new MyMatrix { LineNumber = 1, ColumnNumber = 1 }.GenerateRandomMatrix()
        };

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        int untransposableMatricesCount = 0;
        foreach(MyMatrix myMatrix in myMatrices)
         {
             if(myMatrix.IsTransposable)
             {
                 MyMatrix tranposed = myMatrix.TransposeMatrix(myMatrix);
                 tranposed.PrintMatrixToDebug();
             }
             else
             {
                 untransposableMatricesCount++;
             }
         }
        stopWatch.Stop();

        int untransposableMatricesCount1 = 0;
        object mutex = new object();
        // do not start the parallel processing on the UI thread (it is gonna freeze the UI)
        Task<double>.Run(() =>
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch2.Start();

            Parallel.ForEach(myMatrices, myMatrix =>
            {
                if (myMatrix.IsTransposable)
                {
                    MyMatrix tranposed = myMatrix.TransposeMatrix(myMatrix);

                    tranposed.PrintMatrixToDebug();
                }
                else
                {
                    lock (mutex)
                    {
                        untransposableMatricesCount1++;
                    }
                }
            });

            stopWatch2.Stop();
            double runningTime = stopWatch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

            return runningTime;

        }).ContinueWith((action) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Number of untransposable matrices old main thread: " + untransposableMatricesCount);
            Debug.WriteLine("Running time old main thread processing: " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

            Debug.WriteLine("Number of untransposable matrices parallel: " + untransposableMatricesCount1);
            Debug.WriteLine("Running time parallel processing: " + action.Result);
        });
    }
```

Basically what I am just doing are some matrix calculations that are then printed to the debug console.
 In the first part I am generating some matrices then I have some calculations done in the "old style" on the main UI thread.
 Then I have the same calculations done having a parallel approach.

What is confusing me is that I have the debug messages printed twice or being cut even if I call them just once. By debug messages I mean the messages that are printed in the "ContinueWith" call not the elements from the matrices. Below is how they look like:

[image]

I was expecting to see them only once when the Task (Task.Run(...)) that I started had finished.

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong ? And how should I modify the code in order to see the messages (containing info from stopWatch and stopWatch1 variables) printed only once after the parallel Task finished its work.

Here is a simplified version of this code doing string calculations instead of matrix calculations, having the same strange behavior. Meaning that the results from Debug.WriteLine are being printed twice, and I was expected to see them only once.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        List<string> myStrings = new List<string> { "aa", "b", "cc", "d", "ee", "f", "d" };

        int incorrectStringsCount = 0;
        foreach (string myString in myStrings)
        {
            if (myString.Length > 1)
            {
               string reversedString = myString.Reverse().ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                incorrectStringsCount++;
            }
        }
        stopWatch.Stop();

        int incorrectStringsCount1 = 0;
        object mutex = new object();
        Task<double>.Run(() =>
        {
            Stopwatch stopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch2.Start();

            Parallel.ForEach(myStrings, myString =>
            {
                if (myString.Length > 1)
                {
                    string reversed = myString.Reverse().ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    lock (mutex)
                    {
                        incorrectStringsCount1++;
                    }
                }
            });
            stopWatch2.Stop();

            return stopWatch2.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }).ContinueWith((action) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Number of incorrect strings sync call: " + incorrectStringsCount);
            Debug.WriteLine("Running time sync processing: " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

            Debug.WriteLine("Number of incorrect strings parallel call: " + incorrectStringsCount1);
            Debug.WriteLine("Running time parallel processing: " + action.Result);
        });
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: When debugging does this code surely get called just once? There isn't accidentally two delegates for this and it runs twice? Put a breakpoint in the start of the task and see what happens

Comment: Yes, add some tracing at the start of the method too. When you can't find it, write a [mcve] without the matrix stuff.

Comment: I added a break point inside both delegates and each was hit once in each delegate.

Comment: Also i updated the question with a simplified code sample. The added sample it was added to the bottom of the question.

Comment: In the simplfied example put a `Debug.WriteLine("In the function");`  as the first line of the click event handleer and show us the output of that.

Comment: I added the required line, and things gone even stranger , also that line prints twice... even if the event handler gets called only once, since i added a break point on this new added line, and was hit only once. I added also a picture with the results from debug output.

Comment: And the application is just a classic windows forms application if that is influencing somehow this behavior. And the event handler is written for the Click event as the default naming already suggests, no other event handlers were added for the button.

Comment: Add a StopWatch object that gets started with the forum, then make that starting `Debug.Writeline("Time Started: {0}", _globalStopwatch.ElapsedTicks);` if you get the same number twice that means the function really is only running once but something is causing the output to be printed twice in the output window (perhaps two listeners configured)

Comment: I instanced and started the stop watch after the "InitializeComponent()" call in the form constructor.and still the messages were printed twice.